# Triggered Send Error Code: 138 - Exceeded Expiration Policy

Tags: marketing-cloud, error-messages, triggered-send

I reached out to SF Support regarding contacts in the 'errored' count for a triggered send.  They came back with the error code:

> 138 - Exceeded Expiration Policy.

The description found [**here**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_email_send_error_codes.htm&type=5) is vague at best.

Does anyone have more details as to why a contact would have that listed as their error code for a triggered send?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This occurs when the subscriber was in the triggeredsend queue for more than 3 days.

The triggeredsend can queue do the following reasons:

- TS erred causing the job to be stopped and the subscribers to queue, upon restart any subscriber older than 3 days would go to error
- TS was paused causing subscribers to be queued
- Send throttling rate set too low to send all queued subscribers within three days. ex. throttle set to 500/hr and 50,000 in queue, any subscriber in queue longer than three days would have this error