# What happens when Send Throttling a Journey and the DE is overwritten before the original audience is completely sent?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, send-email

Say we have a list of 100,000 records and for deliverability sake we throttle the send to 10,000 records a day... this would take 10 days for the email to deploy, which is fine.

However, on day 7 a new batch of 100K records are written to the Journey DE and it overwrites the existing audience -- of which, there are still 30K records that have yet to deploy -- **will the new "queue" be 130K records, or do we lose the 30K that are yet to be sent from the first batch?**

I've done some digging around here and can't seem to find anything meaningful to answer the question.  My gut tells me the queue simply grows and no records are lost but if someone can confirm that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, you can not have someone sitting in a queue longer than 3 days if you want the email to send to them. They will encounter a [triggeredsend expiration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_june_2018_ts_expiration.htm&type=5) error.

Also answered in this [stack exchange post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301503/triggered-send-error-code-138-exceeded-expiration-policy/301506)

In the other part of your question, the entry source DE is not leveraged once a contact is injected, and is common that this DE is overwritten. Overwriting this DE would not affect any activity/queue within a journey